# Search query in mongodb using AND OR

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Search the record with different query params.

**data**

```
{
"tags" : [ 
    "salt", 
    "tissue"
],
"title" : "test 1",
"category" : "food",
"description" : "food details"
"__v" : 0
},
{
"tags" : [ 
    "sauce"
],
"title" : "test 2",
"category" : "food",
"description" : "sauce food 2"
"__v" : 0
}
```

**Problem**

How to get the result based on query params if it exists

**Case 1** if query params are title=te&tags=salt then in result it should get 2 records.

**Case 2**
If the query param is tags=salt then it should give 1st document in the result

**Case 3**
If the query param is title=test 1 then it should give 1st document in the result

**Case 4**
If the query param is empty then it should give all the document in the result

I don't know who to create a dynamic **where** clause in MongoDB

I am using this below query for this which is not working

```
let tags = req.query.tags ? req.query.tags : '' 
let title = req.query.title
if(tags || title){
query.find({
  $or: [
        { "title": new RegExp(title, "gi") },
        { "description": new RegExp(title, "gi") }
        ,
        { tags: {$in: tags.split(',')} }
      ]
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hjgWZAEZeiO)

```
db.collection.find({
  $and: [
    {
      $or: [
        {
          "title": {//Used regex syntax
            $regex: "te",
            $options: "gi"
          }
        },
        {
          "description": {
            $regex: "te",
            $options: "gi"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      tags: {
        $in: [
          "salt"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

[Regex syntax mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) you could use the same in the code.

Comment: It's working for the current problem, But the problem is if I test for different cases it's not working. Check this [example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_drSBFeSBTM). In this case, it should give 2 result. What's your thoughts?

Comment: Title **test 2** exists in 2nd document and **salt** included in the first document then why it gives 1 document in response

Comment: You have `and` condition which means all the conditions to be true. In second case you don't have salt. Change to or condition in that case

Comment: I think we should create a dynamic clause for the query. View this [case](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Iog08dTHtwX)

Comment: I don't understand. You could club all three under one or condition. Can you elaborate your req

Comment: ok, you need to do that if/else in node.js. Query will work

Comment: Any suggestion on how it will work @Gibbs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227499/discussion-between-adam-and-gibbs).